# Installing ssh2 with php 5.5

Tags: php, pecl, libssh2

Im working on debian wheezy and trying to install SSH2 for php 5.5 (installed from the dotweb repo)
I tried to do it with the pecl command and manually downloading it from http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2

But in both ways, I get this error during the make step:

> /tmp/pear/temp/ssh2/ssh2.c:1154:2: error: unknown type name
>   'LIBSSH2_AGENT' /tmp/pear/temp/ssh2/ssh2.c:1173:8: warning: assignment
>   makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] make:
>   *** [ssh2.lo] Erreur 1

I searched for a solution everywhere but found nothing similar.
Anyone?

Thanx a lot.